# Bash: Pass $VAR to rm

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a `rm` bash command that will ignore a certain directory thats in an environment variable. This is what I have tried

`rm -rf !($VAR)`

This keeps giving a syntax error. It works if I don't use a variable such as `rm -rf !(directory_name)` but I need this to be based on the variable. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: it works for me in bash 3.2.57 and 4.2.37.

Comment: Try `!(${VAR})`. Maybe bash is trying to find a variable `VAR)`. The `{}` will avoid that.

Comment: @Munir `)` is not a valid character for an identifier; `bash` is not trying to expand `VAR)`.

Comment: How are you setting the value of `VAR`? What is the *exact* error you are getting?

Comment: @chepner Doesn't hurt to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $VAR contains spaces? Try using !("$VAR")